# How can i update a database from another activity?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-activity, sql-update

I am pretty much a newbie and I want to update an database from another activity. That means I have a first activity where I am writing a DataBaseHandler (public class MyDatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper).

Than, in a second activity I am adding some data:

```
MyDatabaseHandler db = new MyDatabaseHandler(this);
Contact peter = new Contact(1,"Peter", 27);
db.addContact(peter);
```

Now I want to change Peter's age from 27 to let's say 28, I want to do that from another activity. So, I am writing in a third activity:

```
MyDatabaseHandler db = new MyDatabaseHandler(this);
Contact peter = new Contact(1,"Peter", 28);
db.updateContact(peter);
```

But it doesn't work. I thought if I am giving the same KEY_ID, in this case 1, I can change the entry from wherever. But it seems that I am wrong. Can 
Somebody explain to me what is the right way?

Thank you!

P.S. If I am doing the update from the same activity it works all fine, But not if I am doing the update from another activity : (

Here is my update method:

```
 public int updateContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getAge());


    return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
}
```

Comment: please post your updateContact(Contact contact) method from your database handler

Comment: And what is meaning of "it doesn't work"? Values are not updated? Or does it throw some exception? If yes, post logcat error, too

Comment: how can i enter some code in the comments???

Comment: public int updateContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
 
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
        values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getAnzahl());
 
        
        return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
    }

Answer (score 0):

You have to define an indipendent class to interact with db, not to include the code in an activity. Better you have to use ContentProvider.

Answer (score 0):

use this code

Sorry My English is Not to Good .. SO please ingore it.

```
**DBAadapter db = new DBAadapter(this);
        db.open();
        thou = db.getAllFamilyMembers();

        Log.v("log"," thoughts " + thou); 
        db.close();**
```

In this DBAadapter is which class when your database open close method.

And getAllFamilyMembers() is the  DBAadapter  class method.

then you get data in other activity using Above code.

Comment: You didn't understand where is the problem

Answer (score 0):

You are in for trouble extending SQLiteOpenHelper. As stated by the documentation it is for managing creating and updates(when updating published apps). Please save yourself a lot of grief later, and look into *SQLitedatebase and more specific SQLiteClosable.*

**http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html**

The relevant code for a more direct answers is in your helper class. But... Save yourself :-)

Comment: A contentprovider is another option like the other answer points out, but that is much more overhead than this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a class like this:

```
public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper  {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database.db";

    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Contacts";

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private SQLiteDatabase myDb;

    public DatabaseInterventi(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        if(myDb == null || !isMyDbOpen())
            myDb = getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) { 

        Log.i("DatabaseHelper", "onCreate!");

        // Check if table already exists
        if(!isTableExists(TABLE_NAME)){

        Log.i("DatabaseHelper", "Create Table in DB");

        String sql = "CREATE TABLE {0} ({1} INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + 
        " {2} TEXT NOT NULL,{3} TEXT NOT NULL, {4} INTEGER NOT NULL);";

        db.execSQL(MessageFormat.format(sql, InfoDBIntervento.TABLE_NAME, "id","Name","Surname","Tel"));

    }
    public void insertContact(String name, String surname, int tel){

        if(!myDb.isOpen())
            openDB();

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("Name", name);
        cv.put("Surname", surname);
        cv.put("Tel", tel);

        myDb.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);

        myDb.close();
    }
    public void updateContact(String name, String surname, int tel){

        if(!myDb.isOpen)
            openDB();

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        if(name != null)
            cv.put("Name", name);

        if(surname != null)
            cv.put("Surname", surname);

        if(tel != null)
            cv.put("Tel", tel);

        myDb.update(TABLE_NAME, cv, null, null);

        myDb.close();
    }

    public boolean isTableExists(String tableName) {

        if(!myDb.isOpen())
                openDB();

        Cursor cursor = myDb.rawQuery("select DISTINCT tbl_name from sqlite_master where tbl_name = '"+tableName+"'", null);
        if(cursor!=null) {
            if(cursor.getCount()>0) {
                cursor.close();
                return true;
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
        return false;
    }

    public void openDB(){

        myDb = getWritableDatabase();
    }
}
```

Then, you have to istanziate your Database class and call its methods.

Answer (score 0):

You may try solving the issue by changing SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); to SQLiteDatabase db = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();

A good example may be found here: http://android-er.blogspot.ro/2011/06/edit-row-in-sqlite-database-using.html